# Delta function of two variables

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

this is about integration of delta function where both the arguments are variables

e.g $\delta(x-y)$ where both are x and y are variable now I am now trying to calculate the integral wrt x in following way,

$$\int f(x) \delta(x-y) dx = f(y)$$ where y is also variable.
and $$\int f(y) \delta(x-y) dy = f(x)$$

Please let me know if i am doing it correctly

Thanks

---

Thanks for the clarification,, one more query
can I write

$$\delta(x^2 -y^2) = \frac{\delta(x+y) + \delta(x-y)}{2y}$$
where x and y both are variables..

and

$$\delta(x-y) f(x) = f(y)$$

Please let me know..

Comment: The fact that $y$ is a variable is of no importance if you're integrating with respect to $x$. That is you can treat it like a constant under the first integral. Similarly You can treat $x$ like a constant in the second integral.

Comment: @Digitallis Your comment is confusing. $\delta(x-y)dx$ is unrelated to $\delta(x-y)dy$. The OP simply shouldn't think to $y$ as "a second variable I can integrate over".

Comment: @reuns if x and y are independent variables then is it possible as one can assume other variable  as constant when integrating.

Comment: also can I assume  $\delta(x-y) f(x) = f(y)$ in similar way as $f(x)\delta(x-a) = f(a)$

Comment: No that's the point. Don't think to $\delta(x-y)$ as "in two variables $x,y$". They don't have the same role and you shouldn't try to identify the one with $y$ constant with the one with the role of $x,y$ switched.

Comment: but in integration can i assume one as variable and other as constant

Comment: since I am integrating over one variable

Comment: Why I am asking this question is that in QED many places it occurs when both the arguments of delta function are variable  and they integrate over one variable and assume other as constant  while integrating